# How to add a single day to a UNIX timestamp in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unix, timestamp

I'm adding dates to my database but the issue is that they're a day behind. The data isn't too sensitive so simply adding a day will work. I'm not super familiar with SQL Server and have already searched trying to find how to add a day to a UNIX timestamp.

I simply wanna add a day to my timestamp. For example: `1492560000` is for yesterday and needs to be for today.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Well its in seconds so add 60 * 60 * 24 ?

Comment: Agree with @AlexK.  `select dateadd(S, 1492560000, '1970-01-01') ,dateadd(S, 1492560000 + (60*60*24), '1970-01-01')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can add 60*60*24 for adding a a day. If you want to be able to add additional date parts without mathing it, you can convert the unix timestamp to a SQL one, use dateadd, and then convert it back.

```
declare @date datetime = getutcdate()
declare @unixstartdate datetime = '1970-01-01'
declare @unixdate int = datediff(second, @unixstartdate, @date)

--Add datepart to unix
select
    datediff(second, @unixstartdate, dateadd(/*date part you are adding*/day, /*number of dateparts to add*/1, dateadd(second, @unixdate, @unixstartdate)))

--Here's how we got there
select
    @unixdate AS [current_unix_date]
    ,dateadd(second, @unixdate, @unixstartdate) AS [sql_datetime]   --Convert the unix timestamp to a sql datetime.
    ,dateadd(day, 1, dateadd(second, @unixdate, @unixstartdate))    AS [updated_sql_datetime]   --Add your dayparts. Here we add 1 day.
    ,datediff(second, @unixstartdate, dateadd(day, 1, dateadd(second, @unixdate, @unixstartdate)))  --Convert the updated sql datetime back to unix.
```